# Not able to add data from JSON string into Dictionary<string, double>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary(string, double) which I serialize to store locally.

While reading it back first I save the data to a string. Now when I am trying to deserialize that string and add to 
dictionary(string, double),I am getting en exception -

> "System.InvalidOperationException"  with information "Cannot convert
>   object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Double]'"

```
Dictionary(string, double) dict = new Dictionary(string, double)();
string jsonDictData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
```

=====================================================================

```
string dataAfterRead; // contains data locally stored.
dict = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Dictionary(string, double>>(dataAfterRead);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET does this...

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

More examples: [Serializing Collections with Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm)

Or-
You can do it natively since net 3.5 with jsonserializer.

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonText);
var place = dict["place"]; // "xyz"
```

Here is a simple tutorial for your case: [Quick JSON Serialization/Deserialization in C#](http://procbits.com/2011/04/21/quick-json-serializationdeserialization-in-c)

Requires the `System.Web.Extensions` reference. If you can't find it, your program is probably using a Client target framework. Use a "Full" target framework.

For your case it will look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(YourJson);
```